# Preserve 3D no longer working in Firefox 58?

Tags: android, ubuntu, firefox

[image]I recently upgraded to the latest version of Firefox and Preserve 3D is no longer functioning as it should. When viewing the element in the DOM inspector, the element appears to be rendering in 3D in the correct place, but in the browser all the content is rendered as a  flat rotating object. The code below worked perfectly fine in Firefox 35 through 57. This impacts both Firefox 58 for Ubuntu and Firefox 58 for Android.

The CSS I am using is as below:

```
@keyframes spinner {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

#stage {
  margin: 1em auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
  -moz-perspective: 1200px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  position: block;
}

#spinner {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-name: spinner;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(0);
  transform: rotateZ(0);
}

#spinner:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#spinner img {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transform-style: inherit;
}
```